# Error message using sDNA Prepare Network

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, sdna

I'm preparing a road network using the sDNA Prepare Network tool on QGIS 2.18.28. My OS is Windows 10 64 bit.

I get the following error message:

```
Algorithm Prepare Network starting...
**********************************************************************
WARNING: sDNA ignores your selection and will process the entire layer
**********************************************************************
Running external command: "D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe" "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\bin\sdnaprepare.py" --im "net=D:/MEGAsync/lbm/nanjing_roads_project.shp" --om "net=D:/MEGAsync/lbm/qgis/sdna/nj_prepare.shp;errors=D:/MEGAsync/lbm/qgis/sdna/nj_prepare.shp" "start_gs=;end_gs=;xytol=;ztol=;action=REPAIR;nearmisses;duplicates;isolated;splitlinks;island=;data_absolute=;data_unitlength=;data_text="

sDNA sdnaprepare config: start_gs=;end_gs=;xytol=;ztol=;action=REPAIR;nearmisses;duplicates;isolated;splitlinks;island=;data_absolute=;data_unitlength=;data_text=
Loading DLL c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\\x64\\sdna_vs2008.dll
ERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\bin\sdnaprepare.py", line 4, in <module>
ERR:     commandline_integral_prepare("sdnaprepare")
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\commandline_integral_prepare.py", line 103, in commandline_integral_prepare
ERR:     dll = options.dll)
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\runcalculation.py", line 58, in runcalculation
ERR:     tablecollection1d = TableCollection()
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 215, in __init__
ERR:     self.dll=_dll()
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 38, in _dll
ERR:     __initialize_dll()
ERR:   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA\sdnapy.py", line 74, in __initialize_dll
ERR:     __dll_instance = windll.LoadLibrary(str(__sdna_dll_path))
ERR:   File "D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 444, in LoadLibrary
ERR:     return self._dlltype(name)
ERR:   File "D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
ERR:     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
ERR: WindowsError: [Error 14001] Ó¦ÓÃ³ÌÐòÎÞ·¨Æô¶¯£¬ÒòÎªÓ¦ÓÃ³ÌÐòµÄ²¢ÐÐÅäÖÃ²»ÕýÈ·¡£ÓÐ¹ØÏêÏ¸ÐÅÏ¢£¬Çë²ÎÔÄÓ¦ÓÃ³ÌÐòÊÂ¼þÈÕÖ¾£¬»òÊ¹ÓÃÃüÁîÐÐ sxstrace.exe
External command completed
ERROR: PROCESS DID NOT COMPLETE SUCCESSFULLY
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm Prepare Network finished
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alas Windows 10 is not officially supported by sDNA yet. Some suggestions however

1. You may find that windows 7 compatibility mode on `"D:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe` helps, though this is a guess as I don't have a windows 10 installation to test.
2. It may be an [issue with the C++ redistributable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.computer/kWJDTgW59f4)

The root cause is with the Python ctypes module loading a side-by-side DLL; something has changed which upsets this process Windows 10. For someone with programming experience that would be the most fruitful avenue to explore as sDNA is soon to be released as open source. (Technically you can already edit the source of all the Python components; an open source license will sensibly make that legal :) ).